# How to allow empty input in calling system object

Tags: matlab

I have a MATLAB System object

```
classdef Equalizer < matlab.internal.Helper & matlab.system.mixin.Propagates
    ...
    methods(Access=protected)
        function [xo,yo] = stepImpl(obj,x,y,varargin)
           ...
        end
    end
    ...
end
```

after successful object creation, I have trouble in calling it with empty input values.

```matlab
eq = Equalizer;  % ok
eq(x,y,[]);      % error: Empty on input 3 is not allowed
```

Note that I Have no `inputValidateImpl` function to restrict the input.

My question is How to allow empty input in calling system object, are there any class methods that allow me to implement/override?

Comment: Did you mean to call `eq.stepImpl`?

Comment: yeah, since Matlab 2016b, `eq()` is an equivalent to `eq.step()`. `step` defined in `matlab.System` class will call `obj.stepImpl()` which should be implemented in the child class, which is Equalizer here.

Comment: What are you doing with `varargin`?  If you pass `[]` as an argument, you've passed something and not nothing.  `varargin` is now a 1x1 cell array (*not* empty).  Why not do only `eq(x, y);`?